# i have install mongodb using tar file as explained in mongo website after all when i run mongod command in my terminal its getting error saying

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.121+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically
>   disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify
>   --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.137+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB
>   starting : pid=797 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit
>   host=Nayanas-MacBook-Pro.local
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.137+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version
>   v4.2.2
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.137+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 
>   a0bbbff6ada159e19298d37946ac8dc4b497eadf
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.137+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator:
>   system
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.137+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.137+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build
>   environment:
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.137+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch:
>   x86_64
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.137+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   target_arch: x86_64
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.137+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.145+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in
>   initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found.,
>   terminating
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.146+0530 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown:
>   going to close listening sockets...
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.146+0530 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing
>   socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.147+0530 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping
>   further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.148+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
>
> 2020-01-02T13:26:14.148+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down
>   with code:100

Comment: Does the db directory per the error message `exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating`?

Comment: i have changed the port and the path and now it =s working fine